# Unable to deploy Activiti 6 on Tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, java

I am trying to deploy the Activiti 6.0 WAR on Tomcat 9 using the command line. I have copied the WAR file in the webapps directory when I restart Tomcat 9 it extracts the archive but the app is not accessible from the browser. I tried deploying the application from the Tomcat Web Application Manager GUI and I get an error message

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/activiti-app] could not be started
```

[image: Screenshot of the Tomcat Web Applicayion Manager]

I checked the Catalina.out file in the logs folder and found these messages.

```
30-May-2020 10:47:57.402 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-23] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.activiti.app$
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bootstrapper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.f$
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
            at org.activiti.app.servlet.WebConfigurer.contextInitialized(WebConfigurer.java:62)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4686)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5147)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1418)
            at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:700)
            at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:223)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate org.activiti.app.conf.Bootstrapp$
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
            ... 44 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/app/conf/DatabaseConfiguratio$
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
            ... 46 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate]: Factory method 'transactionTemplate' threw e$
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
            ... 58 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/app/conf/DatabaseConfiguration$
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:322)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe3c95a1.annotationDrivenTransactionManager(<generated>)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration.transactionTemplate(DatabaseConfiguration.java:225)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe3c95a1.CGLIB$transactionTemplate$6(<generated>)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe3c95a1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7a6d3931.invoke(<generated>)
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe3c95a1.transactionTemplate(<generated>)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
            ... 59 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'annotationDrivenTransactionMa$
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
            ... 80 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/app/conf/DatabaseConfigurati$
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:322)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe3c95a1.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration.annotationDrivenTransactionManager(DatabaseConfiguration.java:195)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe3c95a1.CGLIB$annotationDrivenTransactionManager$3(<generated>)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe3c95a1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7a6d3931.invoke(<generated>)
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe3c95a1.annotationDrivenTransactionManager(<generated>)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
            ... 81 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exc$
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
            ... 102 more
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
            at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:925)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(DatabaseConfiguration.java:175)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe3c95a1.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$5(<generated>)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe3c95a1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7a6d3931.invoke(<generated>)
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
            at org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe3c95a1.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
            ... 103 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
            at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:154)
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:307)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1799)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
            ... 118 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
            at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
            at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
            at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:445)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:96)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
           at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:148)
            ... 122 more
30-May-2020 10:47:57.403 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-23] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate contai$
30-May-2020 10:47:57.405 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-23] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/activiti-app] startup failed due to previous errors
10:47:57,407 [http-nio-8080-exec-23] INFO  org.activiti.app.servlet.WebConfigurer  - Destroying Web application
30-May-2020 10:47:57.407 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-23] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [org.activiti.app.se$
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
                at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:83)
                at org.activiti.app.servlet.WebConfigurer.contextDestroyed(WebConfigurer.java:125)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4732)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5397)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1418)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:700)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:223)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
30-May-2020 10:47:57.410 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-23] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [activiti-app] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver$
30-May-2020 10:47:57.415 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-23] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [activiti-app] appears to have started a thread named$
 java.base@11.0.7/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytesBytes(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.7/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:385)
 java.base@11.0.7/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:153)
 java.base@11.0.7/java.io.InputStream.readNBytes(InputStream.java:490)
 java.base@11.0.7/java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:807)
 java.base@11.0.7/java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:1007)
 java.base@11.0.7/java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(JarFile.java:390)
 java.base@11.0.7/java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:509)
 java.base@11.0.7/java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:470)
 org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:98)
 org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:256)
 org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
 org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
 org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
 org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2302)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1334)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1040)
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1010)
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$100(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$5.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1260)
30-May-2020 10:47:57.438 INFO [Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instanc$
```

These are my PATH and JAVA_HOME settings

```
sridhar@ub-s-2vcpu-4gb-blr1-01-02:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/sridhar/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/bin:/home/sridhar/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/bin
sridhar@ub-s-2vcpu-4gb-blr1-01-02:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
sridhar@ub-s-2vcpu-4gb-blr1-01-02:~$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I am at a deadend and don't have know what could be a reason for this issue. Any clues on what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by making use of java 1.8.

Execute this command on your terminal then restart the terminal:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```